# XNA - adding items to a list and draw them

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm making a Space Invaders clone in XNA. I created the invaders array and added their movement logic. I want to make them shoot bullets. So I've been following a tutorial about it and used only the code I need. But still no bullets are drawn on the screen. Here's my invader class, I removed what is not related to the question from it:

```
class botInvaders
{

    public botInvaders(Texture2D newBulletTex)
    {
        bulletsList = new List<blasterLasers>();
        bulletTex = newBulletTex;
        botInvadersHealth = 5;
        currentDificultyLevel = 1;
        bulletDelay = 40;
        isVisible = true;
    }

    public static Texture2D botInvaderTex, bulletTex;
    public static Rectangle botInvaderHitBox;
    public static Vector2 botInvaderOrigin;
    public int botInvaderCurrentFrame = 1, botInvaderFrameWidth = 52, botInvaderFrameHeight = 90, bulletDelay, botInvadersHealth, currentDificultyLevel, invaderRows = 3, invaderCollumns = 10; // invaderRows = 5 // For 50 invaders
    public static Rectangle[,] botInvadersRect;
    public bool isVisible;
    public List<blasterLasers> bulletsList;

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        botInvaderTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\botInvaders\\normalInvaders\\invaderShip1");
        bulletTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\botInvaders\\normalInvaders\\botInvaderLaser");
        botInvadersRect = new Rectangle[invaderRows, invaderCollumns];
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
            {
                EnemyShoot();
                UpdateBullets();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(Texture2D invadersTex, Rectangle[,] invadersDestinationRect, Nullable<Rectangle> invadersSourceRect, Color invadersColor, float invadersRotation, Vector2 invadersOrigin, SpriteEffects invadersEffects, float invadersScale, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(botInvaderTex, botInvadersRect[r, c], botInvaderHitBox, Color.White);
                foreach (blasterLasers bulletSpawn in bulletsList)
                {
                    bulletSpawn.Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateBullets()
    {
        foreach (blasterLasers bulletsSpawn in bulletsList)
        {
            bulletsSpawn.bulletPos.Y = bulletsSpawn.bulletPos.Y + bulletsSpawn.bulletSpeed;
            if (bulletsSpawn.bulletPos.Y >= -632)
            {
                bulletsSpawn.isVisible = false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bulletsList.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!bulletsList[i].isVisible)
            {
                bulletsList.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void EnemyShoot()
    {
        if (bulletDelay >= 0)
        {
            bulletDelay--;
        }

        if (bulletDelay <= 0)
        {
            blasterLasers newBullet = new blasterLasers(bulletTex);
            newBullet.bulletPos = new Vector2(botInvaderHitBox.X + botInvaderFrameWidth / 2 - newBullet.bulletTex.Width / 2, botInvaderHitBox.Y + 90);
            newBullet.isVisible = true;
            if (bulletsList.Count() < 20)
            {
                bulletsList.Add(newBullet);
            }
        }

        if (bulletDelay == 0)
        {
            bulletDelay = 40;
        }
    }
}
```

I initialize the class in Game1:

```
// Create a var
botInvaders botInvader;
// Init it
botInvader = new botInvaders(botInvaders.bulletTex);
// Load Content
botInvader.LoadContent(Content);
// Update
botInvader.Update(gameTime);
// Draw Invaders
botInvader.Draw(botInvaders.botInvaderTex, botInvaders.botInvadersRect, botInvaders.botInvaderHitBox, Color.White, 0f, botInvaders.botInvaderOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f, spriteBatch);
```

Could the problem be that I'm not actually drawing the bullets?
Or I'm not adding any bullets to the list?
If I debug I can see:

```
bulletsList Count = 0
_size 0
_items [0] null [1] null [2] null [3] null
```

EDIT:

blasterLasers class:

```
public class blasterLasers
{
    public Texture2D bulletTex;
    public Vector2 bulletOrigin, bulletPos;
    public bool isVisible;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public Rectangle boundingBox;

    public blasterLasers(Texture2D newBulletTex)
    {
        bulletSpeed = 10f;
        bulletTex = newBulletTex;
        isVisible = false;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(bulletTex, bulletPos, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are removing the bullets from bulletslist when you call UpdateBullets, so when you go call Draw, it loops through bulletList, which is empty, hence nothing is drawn.

Comment: Agreed, note that the condition for removal is Y >= -632, which is likely *always* true.

Comment: Agreed, but without more information on blasterLasers it's hard to tell. I suggest putting some breakpoints in, and seeing if this is this issue.

Comment: Going to post my blasterLasers class too then.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET even if I comment that out still no bullets are drawn on the screen.

Comment: @Charlie Your list count is 0, so either nothing ever adds (set a breakpoint to see if that code is reached) or you are removing right away. If you didn't comment carefully, you might not have done anything... Please verify that you are adding and *not* removing.

Comment: It reaches the `.Add()` and I commented out all the bullet removal conditions - still no bullets.

Comment: @yhax Alright if I can't find the solution for this what do you guys suggest that I should do to make the invaders shoot?

Comment: It's really tough to say without being able to debug this. The only other two things I can think of is: Are you sure that this line:             newBullet.bulletPos = new ... is not always setting the same position for every bullet, and are maybe getting drawn but behind something, because they are all in the same place every time? Another thing is maybe it is calling draw, but the co-ords on the sprite batch are wrong, its not looking at the right part of the sprite file if that makes sense. You need to debug some more, print out some co-ords etc. Maybe draw nothing but bullets to start.